# Construct string with incremental dot notation

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I'd like to be able to dynamically construct an xpath, preferably using incremenetal functional dot notations, example:

```
var xpath = new Xpath().base.result.entry.name['ethernet1/1']
```

Would return something like:

```
/device[@type=base]/result/entry[@name='ethernet1/1']
```

So far I got this code:

```
public class Xpath
{
    private StringBuilder _stringBuilder { get; set; }

    public Xpath base => this.Append("base");
    // other similar (^) properties here

    internal Xpath Append(string value)
    {
        _stringBuilder.Append(value);
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code works, but if possible, I'd like to avoid having to write a property for each possible increment, and rather have it just construct a string based on all the properties of a dynamic object.

I've tried taking a look at what I can do with the `dynamic` property, but I've been unable to find any examples that can help me in the right direction.

Have anyone had a similar issue, or have any better suggestions on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that `base` is a reserved keyword? Anyway: what speaks against `new Xpath().Append("base").Append("result")...`?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, it was just an example :) but anyway. Yeah, I was considering just using Add/Append, but it got me curious if there was any other way to do this for the purpose of writing less code.